# cocos2d errors when changing iOS target

Tags: ios, build, cocos2d-x

I have an iOS app which has been using cocos2dx. The app works fine when the app and the cocos library both target iOS 6 but when I change it to 7 or 8 i suddenly get this error appearing.

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: basic_string

Why does this appear all of a sudden

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a crash in your code, iterating over a string and accessing out of bounds.

Try debugging your application in XCode and adding a breakpoint for all exceptions:
http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/01/23/xcode-tips-1-break-on-exceptions

You can then follow the call stack up into the offending code.